# 'wkhtmltopdf.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

Trying to generate wkhtmltopdf through html with this code.But gives me this error.

```
 require_once("wkhtmltopdf.php")
 $html=file_get_contents("http://www.facebook.com");
 $pdf = new WKPDF();
 $pdf->set_url($html);
 $pdf->render();
 $pdf->output(WKPDF::$PDF_EMBEDDED,‘sample.pdf’);
```

WKPDF program error.
RESULT: 1
  STDERR:   'wkhtmltopdf.exe' is not recognized as an  internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
 STDOUT

Comment: You probably need to install the executable file as it seems to be missing : https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html  
What is the code  in the wkthmltopdf.php file ?  
Also, at line 1 the filename should be quoted, is it a typo ?

Comment: File name is quoted perfectly, Its typo in  stackoverflow

Comment: wkhtmltopdf.php contains all functionality, its downloaded from the site

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is a command line utility, so you probably downloaded a wrapper for it.  What did you downloaded exactly ?

Comment: Which site? Normally the application needs to be installed separately.

Comment: https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf-bindings... downloaded from here.

Comment: I have set path of my executable inside enviornment variable..now i am, running with below path,

$output= shell_exec("wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com C:/ac.pdf 2> output

still gives me wkhtmltopdf not recognized as internal or external command